# How to set the oscilloscope to measure potential between two points that aren't ground?

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement

We have to measure the voltage across a-b in this circuit with an analog oscilloscope, but neither of these points are grounded. How should we put the channels of oscilloscope to perform the measurement?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the ground clips of two scope probes on the ground of the circuit (the one denoted with ground symbol). Then put Channel A on point A, channel B on point B, and then use the Math function of the scope to display the difference between two signals.

Comment: Why can't you put the ground pin on B and the probe on A - just like it would be done with a multimeter?

Comment: @MikeSpark - because a multimeter is floating and "isolated". If you clip the scope ground to B then you're probably shorting out R2 through your scope.

Comment: @MikeSpark The oscilloscope's ground is most likely a single common point between all of the probes an it COULD be the same ground as a power power supply of the circuit. Now imagine what will happen when you connect the power supply's ground to one of the points.

Comment: Because the scope probe ground should be at the same potential as the earth ground.  If the circuit is also connected to earth ground, then your scope probe ground will short your circuit to ground at a point it wasn't designed for - incorrect measurment guaranteed, possible sparks and "kaboom" depending on C1 and the amount of current that Vs can deliver.

Comment: That was the solution that also I consider, but our analog oscilloscope has not the analog math function.Can we make this measurement through other points or with one channel? I mean if we can make nodal analysis from other nodes to measure that A-B difference.I wonder because I don't know if there is any possible other way to do that. I thought to make nodal analysis with the circuit of oscilloscope been connected to above circuit so that oscilloscope not changing the measure.

Comment: @pawo38 Well, you can just display the two signals and try to estimate the difference by yourself. Or use a differential probe (but it will cost you...)

Comment: @pawo38 The fact that your scope is *analog* is a crucial detail that you did not mention in your question. I have added this detail. In future, if comments elicit information that is absent from the question, edit the question and add the details. (People won't read endless comment threads to get all the details.)

Comment: If your scope can invert one channel and add both channels, it has the math function. Most analog scopes can do this, I can't remember the last one I saw that couldn't. (Both channels must be on the same voltage range, of course!)

Comment: I've never seen an analogue scope *without* an add/subtract function. It may not be called 'math' and may be moderately hard to find (for instance 'add' + 'invert') but even the huge valve driven scope I got from my late grandfather 30 years ago which was outdated at the time had this facility.

Comment: What about differential probes? It could solve his problem ;)

Comment: Even without "invert and add", it is pretty trivial to read the voltage levels of A and B off of the graticule and subtract one from the other.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan It is not always true. In this case we are going to have two sine waves with shifted phases, so it won't be that easy.

Comment: Actually it is. If they're sine waves you can compute the RMS voltage from 0.707 x Vpeak. Subtract the smaller Vrms from the larger, done. Invert and add would give you a single complex waveform which would make it not so easy.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan But who said they want the RMS? Sometimes the complex wave is the desired output.

Comment: Then the problem needs to be specified better. The problem specified "measure the voltage". A waveform is not "voltage". *smirk* But yes, if you want the waveform, then you want invert-and-add. And I agree with the above comments: I've literally never seen a dual-trace scope without that. "Add" is trivial to, er, add alongside "alt" and "chop".

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: Surely the "waveform" is just a voltage that happens to be varying with time?